# JQGrid Footer not properly formatted

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid (the latest, v4.8), but my grid footer is not being properly formatted. In addition, the navigation controls (page number, drop-down, etc) are now showing any values.

I have inspected the grid with Firebug and do not see any issue with the CSS.

I've included an image highlighting the problem:

[image]

Comment: looks like you have bad css. Inspect what's going on with F12 in any modern browser.

Comment: I inspect element with Firebug but there's no issue.. :(

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use?** The reason of the problem could be wrong usage of jqGrid or a bug in jqGrid in some specific situation. One need to have **the demo which reproduce the problem** in both situations. By the way "the footer" is the pager or the bottom pager. The footer can be created with respect of the `footerrow: true` option.

Comment: Updated to latest 4.8 But still same :(

Comment: You should understand that one can't find the reason of the the most problems just by looking on the picture. You have to post the demo which reproduce the problem or at least the fragments of the code, which you use.

Comment: Remove ambiguous and redundant grid tag; edit relevant OP comments into question